# Abstract class between two concrete class - java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, abstract

So essentially, I have sandwhiched an abstract class between two concreate classes and would like the bottom-class of this sandwich to be able to call all the name of the two parent classes. 
This doesn't work, I would like to know why? Not the code, I wrote that without the computer just the logic.

The output I expect after calling get name would be:
customer!middleMan!myShop!

```
public abstract class StoreClerk extends Shop { 
    string name =  "MiddleMan!";

    public getName {
        return this.name + super.getName();
    }

}

public class Shop {
    string name = "myShop!";

    public getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class Customer extends StoreClerk {
    string name = "customer!";

    public getName() {
        return this.name + super.getName();
    }
}

public class void main(String args[]) {   
    Customer ibrahim = new Customer();
    ibrahim.getName();
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this has already been posted!

Comment: `string` isn't something that exists in Java

Comment: @Li357 he wrote that it's pseudocode

Comment: @payloc Where? To OP: This inheritance doesn't make sense. A clerk isn't a shop. A shop can *have a clerk*. A customer is also not a clerk, but a shop can *have customers*..

Comment: @Li357 `Not the code, I wrote that without the computer just the logic.` guess it stands for `pseudocode`. Still, you are right, the code is conceptually wrong. Also, Ibrahim, how do you know it does not work if you did not do it at the computer?

Comment: "This doesn't work" doesn't tell us much. What problem exactly are you facing? Are you getting any compilation error, or exception, or incorrect results?

Comment: Your approach works the way you expect it (after correcting the syntax errors).

Comment: @ibrahim, can you please explain the part you think doesn't work, did you try running fixing the compiler errors?

Answer (score 3):

**Working Code:**

```
abstract class StoreClerk extends Shop {
    String name = "MiddleMan!";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name + super.getName();
    }

}

class Shop {
    String name = "myShop!";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Customer extends StoreClerk {
    String name = "customer!";

    public String getName() {
        return this.name + super.getName();
    }
}

public class Store {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Customer ibrahim = new Customer();
        System.out.println(ibrahim.getName());
    }
}
```

**Your Mistake:** *Although there were many but few that are imp are*

- you were using return in your getName() but you were not defining the function to return anything.

  **Like :**

> ```
> public String getName() {
>       return this.name + super.getName();
>   }
> ```

- You were not displaying any outcome of the code.

  **Like :**

> System.out.println(ibrahim.getName());